# Condvar behaviour after signal, but before mutex release

Tags: linux, synchronization, mutex

I am trying to understand what guarantees I have just after I signalled a condvar.

The basic pattern of usage is, I believe, this (pseudocode):

**Consumer Thread:**

```
Mutex.Enter()
  while(variable != ready)
     Condvar.Wait()
Mutex.Exit()
```

**Producer Thread:**

```
Mutex.Enter()
  variable = ready
  Condvar.Broadcast()
  [Unknown?]
Mutext.Exit()
```

My question is. What am I guaranteed about the [Unknown] point in the code above? I am still holding the mutex, but what can I know about the state of the consumer?

From the Man page, it is unclear to me what state the producer is in after it broadcasts/signals and before it releases the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

From [condition vars](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarOverview):

pthread_cond_wait() blocks the calling thread until the specified condition is signalled. This routine should be called while mutex is locked, and it will automatically release the mutex while it waits. After signal is received and thread is awakened, mutex will be automatically locked for use by the thread. The programmer is then responsible for unlocking mutex when the thread is finished with it.

So, when producer is executing the Unknown section of code, producer is holding the mutex, and the consumer is locked on the mutex until producer releases it.